# How to share a bucket in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Tried sharing a bucket with a colleague
Initially I added the "Storage.Object.Viewer" role, and sent the link https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/bucket_name/
However on opening the link the following error was received:

> You need the storage.objects.list permission to list objects in this
>   bucket. Ask a project or bucket owner to give you this permission and
>   try again.

I added more roles, and finally gave admin rights, but kept getting the same error.

How can I share a bucket with all files? specifically I would like to share with read-only permissions

Comment: Is it possible that you have the wrong email address for them? Adding them as a project admin should be far more than sufficient.

Comment: I accidently used project_name instead of bucket_name in the link.
It was not a permissions issue.
The error message was a bit misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the google account used to access the URL by your colleague is the one you gave permissions to, you need to also grant "Viewer" role at the project level else he wouldn't be able to login to the GCP console and access the bucket.

Answer (score 3):

Although a solution has been discovered for this issue, I'm going to summarise some relevant information which may be useful to someone who stumbles on a similar issue.

Project information isn't required in requests to storage buckets, because bucket names are required to be globally unique on Google Cloud Platform, which means if you specify a bucket name in any request, the request will point to the correct bucket no matter what project it resides within, so permissions for a given user to access that bucket must have been set-up in some capacity.

To allow users to list objects in a bucket, they must have been assigned a role with the storage.objects.list permission. Minimal role's that allow the listing of objects in buckets include:

> Storage Object Viewer

- Which allows users to view objects and their metadata, except for ACLs. They can also list the objects in a bucket.

> Project Viewer

- This roles also provides users permission to view other resources in the project. In terms of Cloud Storage, users can list buckets. They can also view bucket metadata, excluding ACLs, when listing.This role can only be applied to a project.

There are other storage specific roles which allow users to list objects in buckets, but to also have other authorisation, for example, to edit/create/delete objects. They include:

> Storage Object Admin

- Users have full control over objects, including listing, creating, viewing, and deleting objects.

> Storage Admin

- Users have full control of buckets and objects.

For more information on Cloud Storage IAM Roles please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).